# golang archive/tar leads to corrupt archive when adding a buffer as explained by the specs

Tags: go

golang newby here trying to make sense of things.

when I try to follow the example at https://pkg.go.dev/archive/tar@go1.20.7 how to write to a tar file I run into trouble adding the payload.

This bit does not work

```
// add uploadObjet to archive
func uploadObjectToArchive(uo UploadObject, writer *tar.Writer) (err error) {

    header := &tar.Header{
        Name:       uo.Name,
        Size:       int64(len(uo.buffer)),
        Mode:       uo.Mode,
        Uid:        uo.Uid,
        Gid:        uo.Gid,
        Uname:      uo.Uname,
        Gname:      uo.Gname,
        ModTime:    uo.Mtim,
        AccessTime: uo.Atim,
        ChangeTime: uo.Ctim,

        Format: tar.FormatGNU,
    }
    err = writer.WriteHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    _, err = writer.Write(uo.buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

showing the following error upon later inspection of the resulting tar

```
tar -tvf 20230804.tar                                                                                                                     
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
-rw-r--r-- dev/dev 4470 2023-04-11 23:10 /home/dev/test.tst
tar: A lone zero block at 11
```

I somehow think that the buffer is not completely consumed by the writer, but do not understand why.

I then stumbled over another code snippet where io.Copy is used to write the buffer

```
...

    _, err = io.Copy(writer, bytes.NewReader(uo.buffer))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

and this works like a charm.

Obviously I found a way around the problem, but would like to understand why the first piece of code does not work and the second does.

Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: If you think the buffer is not completely consumed by the writer, then check the bytes written value returned by `writer.Write`. If write is short and there is no error, I would consider that a bug since the type conforms to `io.Writer`.

Comment: That may also depend on exactly what `io.Writer` you are wrapping with `tar.NewWriter`, since that is where the actual write takes place. If there's buffering involved, are the buffers flushed in the correct order?

Comment: I create the writer as follows 

var buf bytes.Buffer
writer := tar.NewWriter(&buf)

flushing does not do the trick either 
uo.buffer stays empty